# Should we have a site blog?

Tags: discussion

Many stack exchange sites have associated [site blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs) for things that don't quite "fit" with the Q&A format of the main site.  I think there are quite a few interesting topics we could cover in a blog if we have enough folks interested in contributing posts.

There are a [some guidelines that Stack Exchange provides](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) for starting a site blog, and I think we hit all the high points.

I've left a CW answer here to suggest topics (and volunteer yourself as a writer if you're so inclined) - Ideally I'd like to see us able to put out a post every other week which should be do-able with 3-4 interested contributors.

Comment: GraceNote has done the initial blog setup - our brave volunteers should expect to be dragooned into [the blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13831/) soon so we can get started on initial setup and articles (Since there's no [tag:status-in-progress] I'll leave this one as [tag:status-review] until we go live)

Answer (score 11):

## Blog Topic Ideas

- **Places to Fly**
  Airports with something interesting to do (museums, restaurants, air shows, etc.)
- **Product Reviews**
  Critique a headset, talk about a test flight in a new plane, etc.
- **"I learned about flying from this" style stories**
  Risk Management, in-flight emergencies, mistakes, and other learning experiences.
- **Flight Training**
  Any students in the house? Private training, instrument rating, commercial, etc...
- **Aviation Weather**
  We have at least one meteorologist in the house
- **Aircraft systems, maintenance, etc**
  Mechanics? Owners? Anyone who gets their hands dirty keeping an aircraft in flying shape?
- **Accident Analysis**
  Pick an interesting NTSB report & tear into it - share what you learned with others!
- **Aircraft Design**
  Discuss, disassemble and critique old, current and upcoming plane designs.
- **Intelligent Systems**
  Discuss and speculate on the future of automation in aviation.
- **The Nitty Gritty**
  *This is more oriented towards an enthusiast audience.* Pick up any specific part commonly found in planes and break it down to its nuts and bolts.
- **Aviation Annecdotals**
  Interesting stories straight from the cockpit (or control tower, if you are that kind of person.)

---

## Volunteers?

> For readability I think a simple bulleted list format will work for volunteering :-)
>
> - [Who you are](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/64/voretaq7)
>     What topics you want to blog about

- [voretaq7](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/64/voretaq7)
  Product reviews, Maintenance, Accident Analysis, Places to fly
- [Manfred](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/790/manfred)
  Flight Simulation, Aerospace Engineering/Design
- [casey](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/258/casey)
  Weather, Career progression / training, "I learned from this"
- [Steve V.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/167/steve-v)
  Flight training / instruction, accident analysis
- [roe](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/2/roe)
  Places to fly, European aviation and airspace quirks.
- [Farhan](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/65/farhan)
  Product reviews, Flight training and instruction
- [Articuno](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/2168/articuno)
  Flight training and instruction, Canadian aviation, Science-based aviation (the evidence behind particular claims and practices)

Comment: What is the guidance on whether a topic is better for a blog or the "answer your own question" feature?

Comment: @fooot A lot of things could fall into *both* categories. Site blogs are a good way way to talk about "squishy" topics that would otherwise be too subjective/opinion-based for Q&A -- e.g. "Is the XXX a good headset?", or as an opportunity to go in-depth on specific questions with more research and background than a typical answer gives (e.g. [the IT Security folks do a question-of-the-week](http://security.blogoverflow.com), we could do "accident probes")

Comment: I would nominate Terry for his great experience flying 747 :)