# Aviation Blog: The future

Tags: discussion

We [wanted a blog](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/295/65), and then [got one](http://aviation.blogoverflow.com/). But now there are suggestions that the blogs will be [eliminated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287176/231188).

Besides some interest, and a handful of articles, the blog was not successful. Some active users on Aviation.SE maintain their own blogs.

So at this point, should we keep the blog site or no? If yes, we do need contributors, at least 2-3 articles a month.

Thoughts?

Comment: To be clear: the current blog site will not be kept. If you want to keep the blog, you'll have to re-home it elsewhere.

Comment: [This shows](http://stackexchange.com/blogs) a list of all the blogs and when they were last active.

Comment: If we did not have much interest in a blog here at SE will we have interest in an external blog? I think the issue of integration brought up on Meta is important. I knew we had a blog because I hang out in chat, but I didn't really remember how to get there or know when things were posted to it.

Comment: Can we start from "how to post a blog"?

Comment: I didn't even know where the blog is (not until I read this post, at least). I heard we got one, but never saw a link to it. I think that's an issue.

Comment: Given the last post appears to be several months ago, I think you have your answer on whether or not it should be kept. I use SO everyday and I think I have looked at the blogs once or twice. They are very hidden and not why I come here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speaking as one of the guilty people who agreed to help with the blog and then did more or less nothing, I think we should abandon it:

- If there's been no real interest so far in having and maintaining one, why should there be more interest now? Has something significant changed with this site or its contributors to make it (a lot!) more likely that we could actually support an active blog? IMO, no, but others might disagree
- StackExchange as a whole is [stopping blogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287176/151305) (it seems to be a decision, not just a suggestion), which means that we'd need an external platform. The lack of integration with SE would likely make that less convenient, e.g. keeping the same user names
- Blogging - whether posting or editing/reviewing - is time-consuming. Personally, I'd rather spend that time on the core Q&A activities but of course that's just my own view.
- As Farhan noted, users can easily link to their own blogs if they're interesting for the community